# How to fill a datatable using form fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I have a form with txtbox name, txtbox age and an insert button. I want to fill a datatable called person with these datas, but i dont know how to do. The data base, data set and the datatable are already created, but i dont know how to fill the datatable fields.
Can somebody help me ? 
Easy explenations please, i am a newbie.
I am using vs2015 and SQL server 2008

Comment: There are many, many different ways to accomplish this, as such any given answer would be simply an opinion. Look up documentation on ado.net and perhaps consider using an ORM, simple ones like dapper or microrm might be best for getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data row object for your data table Then Add row to your data table

```
  DataRow workRow = workTable.NewRow();    
  workRow = workTable.NewRow();
  workRow[0] = txtboxname.Text;
  workRow[1] =  txtboxage.Text;
  workTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
```

Comment: How do i make a table instance ?